# Find a probability density function of a sum of variables - random walk

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-walk, density-function

I am currently starting to read through "Fundamentals of statistical and thermal physics" by Federick Reif and I got to chapter 1.10 - **Calculation of the probability density function**.

*In the context of the random walk problem*
Suppose the total displacement $x$ is given by:

$$
\sum^N_{i=1}s_i
$$

where $si$ is the displacement of the $i$th step that follows a probability density function $\omega (s_i)$. Then the probability of a certain sequence of steps being taken is given by:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^N \omega(s_i)s_i
$$

and the probability of the total displacement $x$ lies in the range of $x$ and $x+dx$ is given by:

$$
P(x)dx=\prod_{i=1}^N \int\omega(s_i)s_i
$$

where the limits of integration are subjected to the restraint $x<\sum^N_{i=1}<x+dx$. Now this mess with the limits of integration is solved with the dirac delta function by:

$$
P(x)dx=\prod_{i=1}^N \int\omega(s_i)s_i \delta(x-\sum^N_{j=1}s_j)dx
$$

and this seems reasonable. But suppose I wanted to do a particular case of just two steps and not think about a random walk and just two different, independent random variables $s_1$ and $s_2$ and $x=s_1+s_2$. Now the problem is, what is the pdf of $x$?

If I just used the previous solution I would write:

$$
p(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\omega(s_1)\omega(s_2)\delta(x-(s_1+s_2))ds_1ds_2
$$

which upon rearranging:

$$
p(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\omega(s_1)\omega(s_2)\delta(s_1-(x-s_2))ds_1ds_2dx
$$

and integrating in $s_1$:

$$
p(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\omega(x-s_2)\omega(s_2)ds_2=\omega(s_1)\circledast \omega(s_2)dx
$$

hence $p(x)=\omega(s_1)\circledast \omega(s_2)$ and this is coherent with the fourier transform part that comes next on the book, where the sum of variables just translates to a multiplication i the fourier space, but **this approach doesn't seem doable for more than two variables** unless I do it recursevely, that is, write always $x=s_1+s_2+s_3+\dots +s_N \to x=s_1+y$ where $y=\sum^N_{i=2}$, and use the previous result. But doing it explicitly should return the same result, but the delta dirac disapears after just one integration and I can't seem to get around that. Am I having the correct approach?

Comment: Run. A density is not a probability. Random variables should be treated differently from the values they can take (the usual convention is to use X and x). Probabilities cannot be negative and so they cannot be a product of (possibly negative) displacement terms. If a book is saying otherwise then I would run.